# How to call getFragmentManager on Recycler.Adapter?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am converting ListView of my app to RecyclerView. On ListView, it was very easy to implement OnClickListener but in RecyclerView, we have to do it in adapter. I want to open a new Fragment when user clicks on a item. To do this I have to call FragmentManager in adapter which I am not able to do.
This is my code of RecyclerAdapter:

```
public ListItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Call FragmentManager and add Fragment to it.
            }
        }
```

So, how to call FragmentManager and add Fragments in it. Is there any better way than this like sendingBroadcast or any other method.

Comment: bubble event up to Recycler.Adapter (as now it is in the holder) and set some listener for it (for example the fragment that creates the addapter) - how to do this? it was described here on SO many times

Comment: @Selvin I know how to call FragmentManager in activity or fragment but it is giving me error in Adapter

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You just need an activity context passed in your constructor. Be sure to call `new Adapter(this,...)` from activities and `new Adapter(getActivity(),...)` from fragments.

```
private Context context;

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    FragmentManager manager = ((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
}
```

Comment: FragmentManager manager = ((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();

Answer (score 45):

To add on to the approved answer: if you still get an error you might need to replace this line;

```
FragmentManager manager = ((Activity)context).getFragmentManager();
```

With this

```
FragmentManager manager = ((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
```

For me this was because I was using the `support.v4.app.FragmentManager` instead of the regular `fragmentmanager`

**Still get an error?**

As one comment below pointed out, this might throw a `java.lang.ClassCastException:` and log `... cannot be cast to android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity` (check comments for details)

Their fix was to use this instead (I haven't tested it but it worked for them):

```
((AppCompatActivity)activity).getSupportFragmentManager()
```

Comment: I had the same problem. Thanks :)

Comment: @h8pathak  glad it helped

Comment: Thank you!      This help me.

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.skypoint.cmdroyal.extra.AppControllerVolley cannot be cast to android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity I am having this problem. I am tring to open this from recycler items.. so this line of code is in an adapter class.

Comment: this worked. 
((AppCompatActivity)activity).getSupportFragmentManager()

Answer (score 8):

Make sure to pass context to the ArrayAdapter or RecyclerViewAdpater,So that we can get it inside Adapter Class.

**If your mainActivity is extending Activity then use :**

```
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((Activity)context).getFragmentManager();
```

**If your mainActivity is extending AppCompatActivity then use :**

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Answer (score 6):

Best option would probably be to have the Fragment that instantiates the RecyclerAdapter to implement and interface like this:

```
public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

     private ItemType[] mItems;
     private MRAItemClickedListener mListener;

     public MyRecyclerAdapter(Context ctx, MRAItemClickedListener listener){

        mListener = listener;
        ...
     }

     @Override
     public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
         holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                  mListener.onItemClicked(mItems[position]);
             }
         });
     }

     interface MRAItemClickedListener {
         void onItemClicked(ItemType item);
     }

}

public class MyFragment ... implements MRAItemClickedListener {

    public void onItemClicked(ItemType item){
          // do stuff with item
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

in kotlin you can use this code:

```
    val fm : FragmentManager= (context as AppCompatActivity).supportFragmentManager
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Consider adding an explanation why and how your code solves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You just need an activity context passed in your constructor. Be sure to call new `Adapter(this,...)` from activities and `new Adapter(getActivity(),...)` from fragments.

`private Context context;
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    FragmentManager manager = ((Activity) context).getFragmentManager();}`

Answer (score 2):

Instantiate the fragmentManager in the activity itself.

### MyActivity.java

```
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
 adapter = new CustomAdapter(productsList, fragmentManager);
```

---

### CustomAdapter.java

```
 CustomAdapter implements MyClickListner{
 CustomAdapter(Arraylist<MyProduct>productsList, FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
      this.productList = productsList;
      this.fragmentManager = fragmentManager;
 }

 @override
  clickFunction(){
     Fragment myFragment= new MyFilterFragment();
     ((MyFilterFragment) myFragment).show(this.fragmentManager,"tag");
  }
```

---

### MyClickListener.java

```
public interface MyClickListener(){
   public clickFunction();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is too late for you but to anyone else who might see this.

So instead of doing m vai did you can pass the context of the fragment when you first initialize your adapter.

So in your constructor for your adapter you can add an argument like this

```
 // variable to hold fragment
 private Fragment fragment;

 public MyCustomAdapter(Fragment fragment)
 {
    this.fragment = fragment;
 }
```

and in your fragment you can just initialize if like this

```
 MyCustomAdapter myAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this);
```

finally you can call

```
Fragment fragment = new myNewFragment();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = context.getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
.commit();
```

so you can start a new fragment

Answer (score 0):

You could pass FragmentManager reference while creating viewholder so your class for Viewholder could be as follows

```
class ListItemViewHolder {
FragmentManager manager;
public ListItemViewHolder(View itemView,FragmentManager manager) {
        super(itemView);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.manager = manager;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Call FragmentManager and add Fragment to it.
        manager.beginTransaction...
        }
    }
```