# Load Fragment Dynamically with content on RecyclerView.Adapter Item Clicked

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

New to Android and Java.
Trying to load fragment dynamically with content over the Activity/TabLayout when RecyclerAdapter item clicked. Here is my [bitbucket repo](https://bitbucket.org/q2amarket/mauritiusguide/src). Below embeding the recyclerview code.

```
public class PlacesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PlacesAdapter.PlacesViewHolder> {

    private List<Place> mPlaces;

    public PlacesAdapter(List<Place> mPlaces) {
        this.mPlaces = mPlaces;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PlacesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.place_list_item, viewGroup, false);
        return new PlacesViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PlacesViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

        Place place = mPlaces.get(i);

        viewHolder.itemHeading.setText(place.getPlaceTitle());
        viewHolder.itemExcerpt.setText(place.getPlaceExcerpt());
        viewHolder.itemRatings.setText(place.getPlaceRatings());
        viewHolder.itemRatingBar.setRating(Float.parseFloat(place.getPlaceRatings()));
        viewHolder.itemImage.setImageResource(place.getPlaceImage());

//        viewHolder.itemCardVIew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View view) {
//                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Item Clicked " + getItemCount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//            }
//        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mPlaces.size();
    }

    public class PlacesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView  itemHeading;
        public TextView  itemExcerpt;
        public ImageView itemImage;
        public TextView  itemRatings;
        public RatingBar itemRatingBar;
        public CardView  itemCardVIew;

        public PlacesViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            itemHeading = itemView.findViewById(R.id.place_item_heading);
            itemExcerpt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.place_item_excerpt);
            itemRatings = itemView.findViewById(R.id.place_item_rating_text);
            itemRatingBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.place_item_rating_bar);
            itemImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.place_item_image);
            itemCardVIew = itemView.findViewById(R.id.place_card_view);

            itemCardVIew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Item Clicked! " + itemHeading.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    // load fragment
                    AppCompatActivity activity   = (AppCompatActivity) view.getContext();
                    Fragment          myFragment = new Fragment();
                    activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, myFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why have you commented your code of onClick?

Comment: @Anmol I am trying different things.. so it was just for test

Comment: so onClick is working fine then you just need to use FragmentTransaction to start your Fragment when onClick event is triggered as i shared in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
viewHolder.itemCardVIew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
             Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Item Clicked " + getItemCount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             FragmentManager manager = ((Activity) context).getFragmentManager();
             FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
             fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new YourFragment());
             fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null); //depend's on your usecase
             fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });
```

This should be be your code to start your Fragment Dynamically.Just Replace the commented code by this it should work

Comment: Thanks Anmol, It is showing error (red color) for `getFragmentManager()` Any idea?

Comment: `FragmentManager manager = ((Activity) context).getFragmentManager();`

try this @CodeLover

Comment: Thanks once gain. Now `contenxt` is missing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30867467/7972699

just pass it in the constructor of the adapter and use it