# Cannot open fragment when click on itemView on holder

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-recyclerview, android-fragmentactivity

I trying to use fragment instead of activity as much as possible, in my custom adapter `PostAdapter` I use `holder.itemView.setOnClickListener` method to pass and open `DetailsFragment` at the end, but when I click on any item on recyclerView it's not doing anything

here's the **PostAdapter** Class

```
    public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.PostViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private List<Item> items;

    public PostAdapter(Context context, List<Item> items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PostAdapter.PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.post_item, parent, false);
        return new PostViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PostViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Item item = items.get(position);
        holder.postTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
        final Document document = Jsoup.parse(item.getContent());
        Elements elements = document.select("img");

//        Log.d("CODE", "Image: "+elements.get(0).attr("src"));
//        Log.d("Text",document.text());
        holder.postDescription.setText(document.text());
        Glide.with(context).load(elements.get(0)
                .attr("src"))
                .into(holder.postImage);

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            DetailsFragment detailsFragment = new DetailsFragment();

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

            bundle.putString("url", item.getUrl());
            bundle.putString("itemTitle", item.getTitle());
            bundle.putString("title", item.getTitle());
            bundle.putString("content", item.getContent());
            int youtubeThumbnailImagesetVisibility = 0;

            Element element = document.body();

            String youtubeThumbnailImageSrc = "";
            String youTubeLink = "";
            for (Element e : element.getElementsByClass
                    ("YOUTUBE-iframe-video")) {
                youtubeThumbnailImageSrc = e.attr("data-thumbnail-src");
                youTubeLink = e.attr("src");
                Log.e("YouTube thumbnail", youtubeThumbnailImageSrc);
                Log.e("Youtube link", youTubeLink);
            }

            if (youtubeThumbnailImageSrc.isEmpty()) {
                youtubeThumbnailImagesetVisibility = 8;
                bundle.putInt("youtubeThumbnailImageSetVisibility",
                        youtubeThumbnailImagesetVisibility);
            } else {
                bundle.putString("youtubeThumbnailImageSrc", youtubeThumbnailImageSrc);
                bundle.putString("youTubeLink", youTubeLink);
            }

//             String imageSrc = elements.get(0).attr("src");
//             bundle.putString("blogImage",imageSrc);

            detailsFragment.setArguments(bundle);

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((Activity)context).getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.nav_view,detailsFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView postImage;
        TextView postTitle;
        TextView postDescription;

        public PostViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            postImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.postImage);
            postTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.postTitle);
            postDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.postDescription);

        }
    }
}
```

**DetailsActivity Fragment**

```
    public class DetailsFragment extends android.app.Fragment {

    private TextView titleTextView, contentTextView;
    //   private ImageView blogImage;
    private PicassoImageGetter imageGetter;
    private ImageView youtubeThumbnailImage;
    private FloatingActionButton fab;
    private ScrollView scrollView;
    private SpinKitView spinKitView;
    private Button visitSite;
    private View view;
    private String url,title,content, youtubeThumbnailImageSrc, youTubeLink,sharingContent;
    private int youtubeThumbnailImageSetVisibility;

    public DetailsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_details, container, false);
                spinKitView = (SpinKitView) view.findViewById(R.id.spin_kit);
        scrollView = (ScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
        titleTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
        contentTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.blogContent);
        fab = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        youtubeThumbnailImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.youtubeThumbnailImage);
        visitSite = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.visitSite);

        if(getArguments() != null){
            Bundle bundle = getArguments();
            url = bundle.getString("url");
            title = bundle.getString("itemTitle");
            content = bundle.getString("content");
            youtubeThumbnailImageSrc = bundle.getString("youtubeThumbnailImageSrc");
            youTubeLink = bundle.getString("youTubeLink");
            youtubeThumbnailImageSetVisibility = bundle.getInt("youtubeThumbnailImageSetVisibility");

        }

//        blogImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.blogImage);

        spinKitView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        titleTextView.setText(title);
        contentTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            scrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener((v, scrollX, scrollY, oldScrollX, oldScrollY) -> {
                //   Log.d("ScrollView","scrollX_"+scrollX+"_scrollY_"+scrollY+"_oldScrollX_"+oldScrollX+"_oldScrollY_"+oldScrollY);
                if (scrollY > 0 && fab.isShown()) {
                    fab.hide();
                } else if (scrollY < 22) {
                    fab.show();

                }
            });
        } else {
            scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(() -> {
                int mScrollY = scrollView.getScrollY();
                if (mScrollY > 0 && fab.isShown()) {
                    fab.hide();
                } else if (mScrollY < 22) {
                    fab.show();
                }
            });
        }

        fab.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            sharingContent = "\n" + url;
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,sharingContent);
            sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
        });

        //       String imageSrc = getIntent().getStringExtra("blogImage");
        //       Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(imageSrc).into(blogImage);

      youtubeThumbnailImage.setVisibility(youtubeThumbnailImageSetVisibility);
        youtubeThumbnailImage.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        Picasso.get().load(youtubeThumbnailImageSrc).into(youtubeThumbnailImage);

        youtubeThumbnailImage.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Intent youTube = new Intent
                    (Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(youTubeLink));
            startActivity(youTube);
        });

        imageGetter = new PicassoImageGetter(contentTextView, getActivity());
        Spannable html;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            html = (Spannable) Html.fromHtml(content, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY, imageGetter, null);
        } else {
            html = (Spannable) Html.fromHtml(content, imageGetter, null);
        }

        contentTextView.setText(html);
        spinKitView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        visitSite.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("url", url );

            VisitSiteFragment visitSiteFragment = new VisitSiteFragment();
            visitSiteFragment.setArguments(bundle);

            FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = manager.beginTransaction();

            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.detailsFragment,visitSiteFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        });
        return view;
    }

}
```

I tried to use `android.support.v4.app` and replace this line

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((Activity)context).getFragmentManager();
```

with this

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
```

as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50549533/4205927) but this did not working also

Comment: The problem is you want to add the fragment to non-activity class. Make an interface for listening on click listener and then in the activity you can replace or add the fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

The cause of the problem in this line

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.nav_view,detailsFragment);
```

I tried to replace the navigation drawer view, but I'm supposed to put the view that contains the recyclerView

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.parentLayout,detailsFragment);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Call fragment on activity class**

Fragments should attach to activities. Make an interface implement it in your activity then initial the interface in your adapter. Call the method in clickListener then you can do anything in activity inside the proper method that is invoked by click.

```
holder.nameImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

       yourInterface.OnItemclick();

    }
});
```

Make sure to initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the **onBindViewHolder** you have to implement it like this :

```
holder.nameImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             ...
            //Toast.makeText(mContext,position+  " pozicioni",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Where you have to replace the "`nameImage`".

Comment: replace "nameImage" with What? , If you mean "postImage" I don't need on click to implement on Image click, the view is consists of postImage, postTitle, postDescription, all views consider "itemView" and the problem not in this part!

Comment: so you want to open the fragment by clicking? @MarkDeSpain

Comment: on clicking in any itemView on the recyclerView, this was working when I used Intent and activity, after I convert the DetailsActivity to fragment the problem appeared