# How to get Fragment class name in adapter

Tags: java, android, adapter

I am working on a Android app since I am new I can't find a way to get the fragment class name ReadFragment into the Adapter onBindViewHolder method.Any hint how can I get the class name or index of the fragment since I am using 2 fragments and want to display diferent data in each.

Fragment:

```
public class ReadFragment extends Fragment {

View view;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,


    return view;


}
```

Adapter

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {}
```

Comment: can you give more details

Comment: I have two fragments I need to recognize in adapter witch fragment is selected currently.I have only inCreateView in the fragments

Comment: What about passing the class name of the fragment as a parameter to the adapter's constructor when you create the adapter in the fragment..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Adapter Side

```
// ..
private Class fragmentCls;

public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(..., Class fragmentCls) {
    // ..
    this.fragmentCls = fragmentCls;
}
// ..
```

2. Fragment Side

```
// ..
adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(.., MyFragment.class);
// ..
// recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
// ..
```

So then you can use the `fragmentCls` field to get to know which is the caller fragment..

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the fragment in the container is `instanceof` any `Fragment`

```
Fragment fragment = context.getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
if(fragment instanceof FirstFragmentClass){
   //do something
} else if(fragment instanceif SecondFragmentClass){
   //do something
}
```

Comment: This loud work but I am in Adapter. Or I should create activity for it ?

Comment: loud work mean?? You can do it in the adapter https://stackoverflow.com/a/30867467/16177121